# Why are all testnet transactions currently unconfirmed and all faucets empty?

Tags: testnet

what is happening with btc testnet, all transactions are unconfirmed and all faucets are empty?

For an example that is on of my transactions: 
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/tx/d32652489a8131657ad05fba8a57bb075e16b20567c824ad67ded067f6b350c4/

Comment: I confirm, some of all faucet are empty, i suppose they will reset the testnet ? Never happened since a long time, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I checked there were about 10x as many transactions in mempool as fit in a block. This means it can take easily about 3 hours for a particular transaction to confirm, on average. Strangely, increasing the miner fee does not seem to help the situation.

Unfortunately, the only faucet that ever worked for me (https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/faucet) is now down for maintenance, but there is no indication that it is "empty".

Comment: Hey @Hypertable, thank you for answer. I'll wait and see.

Comment: Hmm it past about 5 hours and still 0 confirmations.

Comment: @savOFF Well my transactions cleared after 3 hours with HIGH miner preference. Yours is only MEDIUM, you might want to try increasing the fee a bit (though even very high fees seem not to guarantee landing you in the next block or two).

Comment: Yes, after a time I've tried with higher fee and I got success, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Testnet has experienced increased amount of transactions from a project called VeriBlock recently. The transactions from faucets are stuck because of low fees. Faucets need to fix their fee estimates. In the meantime if you need testnet BTC you may request some from bitcoin devs, e.g. Jameson Lopp, see his tweet  https://twitter.com/lopp/status/1037362274959278081

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It would be great if you can share more information or links about this.  E.g. what is VeriBlock and why would it cause spam on the testnet?  Is there evidence that this is the cause?  Why is it likely to stop soon?  You can edit your answer to add more info.

Comment: I found this information on the twitter: https://twitter.com/alexbosworth/status/1036312396665516032 - it looks like faucets use too low fees and need to adjust that, see also: https://twitter.com/lopp/status/1037362274959278081